# AD DNS forwarding to ISP

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have an Active directory server (2008) with DNS that is configured as `internal.company.com` and has an active forwarder that forwards all unknown requests to the ISPs DNS. `company.com` is registered and has an active web-page hosted by an external hoster `www.company.com`.

The servers AD and DNS has been installed with DCPromo with standard settings. All works fine.
My question now is, if a client from the internal network (that has this server configured as name-server) requests an unknown address of the internal domain, such as `unknown.internal.company.com`, if this request will be forwarded to the isp's DNS because my DNS does not know this host? If yes, what do I have to configure that this does no more happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't forward the packet. The key to the zone is the last part of the domain. Everything else before it is considered a subdomain of 'company.com'. Requests are only forwarded if the zone doesn't exist on your local DNS at all.

AD DNS is considered authoritative for the domains it holds, and therefore won't be concerned with looking elsewhere if the subdomain is not found.